Jetpack Navigation 2.8.0-beta03 upgrade issues
This is the latest version i used:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.8.0-beta03
Issues start coming right after update, on any navigation on page or list scroll.
Here are few logs from app, and its redundant.
FrameEvents
updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.

ImageReader_JNI
Unable to acquire a buffer item, very likely client tried to acquire more than maxImages buffers

UPDATE:
resolved after updating it to 2.8.0-beta06 version.
please note 2.8.0-beta07 requires SDK 35.

... but the app works as expected? So you are only asking about the logs?

No. There is a lot of lag on scroll or page navigation, in short in all navigations.

@BikramjitSingh Facing similar issue, I am getting way too many logs, small sample of logs: https://i.imgur.com/rnuLNal.png

Yes. So this issue is present as soon as you update navigation library to 2.8.0 - alpha or beta

Resolved after updating it to 2.8.0-beta06 version - marking it solved now.
please note 2.8.0-beta07 requires SDK 35.
